# What does ‘Rock a hat” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

There is the following sentence in Tina Fey’s “Bossypants":

> ”Don Fay dresses well. He has an artist’s eye for mixing colors and
>   prints. He wears tweedy jackets over sweater vests in the winter and
>   seersucker suits in the summer. His great college ring shows off his
>   well-groomed hands. **He can still rock a hat**. - P43.”

I don’t understand what “He can still rock a hat” means.” Neither of CED or OED carries “rock a hat” as an idiom. Nor GoogleNgram does.

What does it mean? Is this phrase Tina Fey’s coinage?

Comment: [Rock](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rock?q=rock#rock-2__14)

Comment: for reference, other similar uses: http://www.gq.com/style/wear-it-now/201307/what-to-wear-with-a-bow-tie or http://holiday.ziploc.com/browse/style/8-ways-to-rock-a-scarf

Comment: Or see the TV series [How I Rock It](http://tv.esquire.com/shows/how-i-rock-it).

Comment: I don't understand the "still". Is there an expiry date for rocking a hat? Maybe when you go from rocking a hat to rocking a chair?

Comment: @Kaz As I understand it, there is an implied *Even at his age* before **he can still rock a hat**. The implication being that most people her father's age would not be able to wear a hat and still look fashionable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it means that he looks good in a hat.

Not sure if UrbanDictionary is a good reference, but this is the definition I mean:

> #### Rockin'
>
> Wearing something proudly and/or looking good wearing something.
>
> *He's really rockin' that new hat of his!*
>   *He's really rockin' that new haircut.*

Taken from [*UrbanDictionary: Rockin'*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Rockin%27&defid=4794123)

Comment: Matt Эллен above [linked to an almost identical definition from Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rock?q=rock#rock-2__14), who are a good reference: **"*informal* Wear (a garment) or affect (an attitude or style), especially in a confident or flamboyant way"**

Comment: If one is going to rock a cranial accessory such as a hat, I must highly recommend that it be referred to also as a "sweet lid". It's more congruent, really.

Comment: @BrianDHall `:-D` Example usage: "At a soirée such as this, it is indeed imperative that one is seen to be rocking a sweet lid"

Comment: UrbanDictioary is a **terrible** reference: just like Wikipedia, anyone can write anything there but, unlike Wikipedia, you can't edit away bad content.

Comment: @DavidRicherby On the other hand, "inaccurate" answers are usually voted down, and like StackExchange, the order of user definitions on UrbanDictionary rises and falls depending on the number of votes.

Answer (score 15):

My eldest son can **rock a hat**. I am the opposite: even great hats look terrible on me.

To *rock a hat* is to look great in a hat.

> On an errand this weekend, I saw these chic summer hats on display.... They’re designed by Eugenia Kim, a New York based milliner. I was tempted to buy one but I’m not sure I can **rock a hat**.

and

> It's not top brands or being able to *rock a hat* or a man scarf...
>   He also can *rock a hat* like nobody's business...
>   She’s got the sound and look of a star... The girl can sing, play piano and guitar, and man, can she *rock a hat*.

I have not been able to find the first use. It doesn't show up once in Ngrams. I'd guess that means it's use is relatively recent. Searching *idioms* with hat yields no *rock a hat* for me. There are a lot of colorful idioms involving hats, but I think this one is just jargon at the moment.

Comment: to "rock a *piece of clothing*" is the idiom, and I'm having trouble searching for it myself. I get better results for "rock a scarf" and "rock a bow tie" but still nothing in Ngrams.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - excellent point! Thank you. I was searching the wrong word in idioms.

Answer (score 7):

To **rock a hat** is a slang term meaning *to wear a hat*. How one looks in the hat is not always relevant, although it can refer to looks depending on how the phrase is used.

In this example the only implication is to *wear a hat*:

> I think I will rock a hat for the party tomorrow night.

Whereas in this one it is strongly suggested that Eric looks good in the hat:

> Eric can really rock that hat!

Comment: This answer is the only one which points out that it can be used simply to mean "wear" and does not always imply "to stylishly/successfully wear". I think your answer could be improved if you specified the difference between your examples - for example is it the use of "will rock" or "can rock" that defines the implication, or just the tone of the sentence? At the least maybe you could restructure the text you use to introduce the examples to show which is which - I'm suggesting an edit to do just that but you could definitely build on it further.

Comment: I "approved" the edit because it improved the quality of the answer without changing it in any substantial way. However, Oral B, is free to rollback to the original.

Comment: If this answer is to be believed, then "he can still rock a hat" is just a way of saying "he hasn't been decapitated yet".

Comment: Your opening sentence makes it sound like "to rock a hat" is a specific term, when really the term is just "rock" and can be applied to any clothing item.

Comment: Downvoted for wrongness. "Rock" is similar to "ace": in OralB's first example, *the only implication is to wear a hat* in the same way that if I say "I think I'll ace that test tomorrow", the "only implication" is that I'll *take* the test. (I.e., the listener has no special knowledge of whether I'll actually do well on the test / look good in the hat, only that I intend to take / wear it.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I have to respectfully disagree with your "ace" analogy, and I firmly stand by "rock" meaning simply to wear.

Comment: @tobyink I think the less extremist way to read it is that the phrase is used as per the second example in the context given in the question.

Comment: The operative word here is "can". The idiom "Jane can wear X" typically means "Jane can wear X and still look fashionable." "Rock" essentially means "wear"; it sometimes implies wearing confidently, but it doesn't say anything about wearing successfully. "I see you're rocking shorts today" isn't a compliment (or an insult), just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

"Rock" (Colloquial) meant to indicate fashion or style attributes such as a haircut or clothing.

"Rock the  tee shirt today."

"Rock the afro."

"Rocking them big gold medallions"

All of these being a similar slang use of "Rock."

Hope that helps. :)